# windows7 hangs on boot into safemode

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

I was having trouble booting windows7 and running it, slow operation etc.
so i went into msconfig, and set the boot to safe-mode check box. 
Unfortunately, the computer hangs before getting into safe-mode... in all the options, for w/wo networking, and command line options.

Is there a way I can uncheck the boot to safe mode option using linux?
where is that flag set? I am sure I just have some nasty malware. I checked the hardware in Linux and everything in working properly.

what can I do to get out of this?
The place where it hangs is on avgidsha.sys.
yes, I installed avg anti-virus.

Comment: Use F8 to get the advanced screen and select "start windows normally", some systems like my lenovo needs to press F3 first, then F8

Comment: The OS is set to boot into safe mode, so when I select boot normaly, it boots into safemode, and hangs.

Comment: [You will have to boot into the recovery environment](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7) or boot from a W7 repair disk, use the command prompt [see step 6 at this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/69585-safe-mode.html)